# What are Carnot groups?

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, geometric-analysis

I'm trying to learn the Pansu differentiability theorem and I need to know what Carnot groups are. Can someone please explain what Carnot groups are? An introductory reference would be greatly appreciated as well.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you need to know that is not explained on the Wikipedia page (found easily by search engine, it would seem)?

Comment: I guess I need an introductory reference with a bunch of examples.

Comment: Does this paper satisfy your needs? http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.7493

Comment: Yes thanks. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: From the algebraic point of view and a characterization among other nilpotent Lie groups, see http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.5295 (esp. 3.2 for the basic facts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I learned the theory of Carnot group or more general subRiemannian manifolds from the thesis of Monti, which can be found here:
http://www.math.unipd.it/~monti/PAPERS/TesiFinale.pdf
In particular, Section 2 is devoted to the proof of Pansu-differentiability theorem.

Another good notes is by le donne, which [can be found here](https://65ac2831-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/enricoledonne/LeDonne_subRiemannian.pdf)
. However the proof of Pansu differentiability theorem is stated without a proof.

By the way, the reference provided above "Gromov, Mikhael Carnot-Carathéodory spaces seen from within. Sub-Riemannian geometry, 79–323, Progr. Math., 144, Birkhäuser, Basel, 1996." is also a nice research suvery.

Answer (score 3):

As an introductory reference, I'm a fan of the book *Stratified Lie Groups
and Potential Theory
for their Sub-Laplacians* by A. Bonfiglioli, E. Lanconelli and F. Uguzzoni.

Answer (score 1):

MR1421823 
Gromov, Mikhael
Carnot-Carathéodory spaces seen from within. Sub-Riemannian geometry, 79–323, 
Progr. Math., 144, Birkhäuser, Basel, 1996.

Comment: The post above would be interesting  for your request:    https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/lecture-16-free-carnot-groups/

Comment: @Zbignev: you entered your comment in the wrong place. You surely wanted to comment on the question, not on my answer.

Comment: Eremeko I do apologize, I'm not a frequent user of the mathoverflow.